# Adding title to rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-rewriting

I have List objects which are shown like this:

www.mysite.com/lists/123

Where 123 is the id of the list.  What I would like to do is add the title of the list the url so it it more informative(for google or whatever).  So I would like it to look like:

www.mysite.com/lists/123/title-of-list-number-123

How do you go about adding to a url like this?  If you just enter:
www.mysite.com/lists/123 w/o the title, should it find the title and then redirect to a new route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep your find-calls as they are (by id), you could do the opposite of what mplacona suggested:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

With this, your find(params[:id]) will work because it'll convert the string to an integer (can only succeed if the number is in the beginning of the string). So this is will actually work:

```
List.find("123-my-title")
```

and will be the same as

```
List.find(123)
```

Read more about this and other ways to accomplish this here: http://gregmoreno.ca/how-to-create-google-friendly-urls-in-rails/

The parameterize will automatically convert the string to a "pretty" url. Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001367

If you want a bit more functionality, I'll suggest [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) aswell.

Answer (score 2):

This article says exactly what you need to do accomplish this.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

**UPDATE**

Have a permalink added to your model, and save as follow to it:

```
def to_param
  "#{permalink}-#{id}"
end
```

On your controller, instead of getting things by the id, get them by the pemalink:

```
@product = Product.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
```

And that's all you need.

The screen cast explains all the steps on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at [friendly id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id), if you're in the mood for a gem/plugin.