# Rails: How to set the page title to URL (Routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I develop my Rails app on the Cloud9.

What I'd like to do is to set a part of title to the URL such as stackoverflow.

(e.g. `example.com/part-of-tile-here`)

Although I found the similar questions, I don't understand what I should do because some of them are old posts, links in the answer are not found.
(e.g. [Adding title to rails route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410652/adding-title-to-rails-route))

I will not use Gem as yet.

It would be appreciated if you could give me any hint.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, Ho Man is right but there are a few caveats to the proposed solution.

First of all, you should override the `to_param` method as well so it actually uses the slug:

```
# app/models/page.rb
def to_param
  slug
end

# ... which allows you to do this in views/controllers:
page_path(@page)
# instead of
page_path(@page.slug)
```

Second, you should use `find_by!(slug: params[:id])` to 1) be up to date (`find_by_xxx` was [deprecated in Rails 4.0 and removed from Rails 4.1](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders)) and 2) to replicate the behavior of `find` and raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error in case no post can be found for the given slug.

Third, I suggest to always keep the slug up to date and include the ID like so:

```
# app/models/page.rb
before_validation :set_slug

def to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug}"
end

private

def set_slug
  self.slug = title.parameterize
end

# ... which allows you to use the regular ActiveRecord find again because it just looks at the ID in this case:
@post = Post.find(params[:id]) # even if params[:id] is something like 1-an-example-post
```

If you care about search engine results, you should then also include the canonical URL in the `<head>` section and/or redirect with a 301 status in the controller to avoid duplicate content which search engines generally don't like:

```
# in the view
<%= tag(:link, rel: :canonical, href: page_url(@page)) %>

# and/or in the controller:
redirect_to(post_url(@post), status: 301) and return unless params[:id] == @post.to_param
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised?view=asciicast) which is roughly what you want.

**tl;dr**

You'll want to save a `slug` which is a parameterized title, delimited by `-` when you save the page. (In a `before_validation` or `before_save`)

For example, "Random Title Of Page" will get `random-title-of-page` generated as it's slug.

```
before_validation :generate_slug
def generate_slug
  self.slug ||= title.parameterize
end
```

In the page controller, you'll need to enable searching by `slug`.

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```